# Probability with sets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The numbers from 1 to 10 are divvied randomly into 2 sets of 5 elements each.

What is the probability that numbers 1 and 2 are in the same set?

My attempt is below:

The total number of ways to divvy 10 numbers into two sets of 5 elements is $\frac{10!}{5!5!}$

The number of ways in which numbers 1 and 2 are in the same set is = $\dbinom{8}{3}+\dbinom{8}{3}$

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: Whichever set contains $1$ also contains $4$ others.  As every non-$1$ choice is equally likely to be $2$,  the answer is $\frac 49$ (which, to be sure, confirms the stated result).

Comment: @Arthur  Yes, I should have noted that.  This just confirms the result.

Comment: @lulu Could I also represent this answer using set notation? $P(A \cap B) = \frac{4}{9}$

Comment: Well.,,.what are your events $A,B$?

Comment: If the two teams were distinguished, then you could let $A$ be the event that $1$ was on the red team, and $B$ the same for $2$.  Of course, $A\cap B$ would then only give you half the cases, so you'd need to multiply the probability by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

In Species language, the structure in the problem is

*a 2-set of 5-sets of A,B, and X*

where A and B are constants.

By definition, C is a constant $ \iff F(C,X) = C \cdot F'(X) $

Here we have:

$ E_2(E_5(A, B, X)) = A \cdot B \cdot E_2(E_5(X))'' $

$ = A \cdot B \cdot E_5E_4(X)' = A \cdot B \cdot  (E_5E_3 + E_4E_4)(X)'$

$ = E_5(X) \cdot E_5(A,B,X) + E_4(A,X) \cdot E_4(B,X) $

The e.g.f. of above is

$$ \left [ {8 \choose 5,3} + {8 \choose 4,4} \right ] ab { x^8 \over 8!} $$

thus, there are 56 good configurations and 70 bad ones.

Then we have to apply the definition of a probability.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct. There are $ {10 \choose 5}$ ways to divvy up the numbers 1 to 10 into 2 sets. The number of ways for 1 and 2 can be in the first set is ${8 \choose 3}$, since we can place 1 and 2 in the first set and then fill in another 3 elements from the 8 remaining ones. Similarly, there is also ${8 \choose 3}$ ways of putting 1 and 2 into the second set, and therefore $2 {8 \choose 3}$ ways to have 1 and 2 in the same set.

Hence, the probability of having 1 and 2 in the same set in this scenario is: 
$$
\dfrac{2 {8 \choose 3}}{{10\choose5}} = \dfrac{4}{9}
$$

Answer (score 1):

That is okay, but consider a simpler way.

The numbers are divided evenly into sets of size five.  That is ten places for the numbers to occupy.

Number 1 will be in one of these places and *four* of the *nine* remaining places will be in the same set.

The probability that number 2 in placed among those *four* of the *nine* places is ………… ?